# Selecting query results into a variable in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I am writing a PL/PGSQL function. It involves processing the results of a query. IIRC, from the documentation, `SELECT INTO` does not work in this instance, however, query results can be stored by creating temporary tables.

I run the following quick test:

```
create function foo() returns numeric as $body$ 
begin 
  create temporary table footable as 
  select * from some_table; 

  return 1.23; 
end; 
$body$ language plpgsql;
```

I then run tested it as follows:

```
select * from foo();
1.23
select * from foo();
ERROR:  relation "footable" already exists
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "create temporary table footable as select * from 
          some_table"
PL/pgSQL function "foo" line 1 at SQL statement
```

So, how can I temporarily cache the results of a query in a variable, for use later on in my stored proc?

I am using PG 8.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more ways - usually best way is creating temp table only once per session [see](http://okbob.blogspot.cz/2008/11/plpgsql-and-temp-tables.html)

Comment: In your test setup the exception is only raised in the first call per session of `test3()`. I would expect it to be slower if you run into the exception more often - like the OP probably will. Also, `where oid ='omega'::regclass` may be faster than `where relname='omega' and pg_table_is_visible(oid)`? The cast to `regclass` checks for visibility automatically.

Comment: I am not sure - a advantage of test3 is using internal caches instead full SQL query. Cast to regclass can raise exception too. You can refresh this test - some queries can be faster on 9.2.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary tables are destroyed at the end of current **session** (not transaction). You can make it disappear after commit/rollback by modifying `CREATE` statement to:

`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE footable ... ON COMMIT DROP;`

Of course you cannot run this `CREATE` more than once **per transaction** as it will give you 
`relation "footable" already exists` error.